# Приключения и злоключения

Tags: этимология

Как я понимаю, в обоих этих словах корень "ключ", да? А какое отношение имеет ключ к событиям, которые обозначаются этими словами?
Спасибо

Comment: Подскажите, по нормам современного русского языка какой корень у слова "приключение"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Корень *ключ-* в русском языке имеет много разных значений и по происхождению он ... тоже разный)
В данном случае корень составной : **к-люч**.
Давайте вспомним такие слова, как *отлучиться, прилучить, залучить, случить* и **получить**!  Общий здесь корень-морф **луч** имеет смысл - соединение, встреча, направление... "Луч солнца золотой..."
Старинное слово *к/лючение* = *с/лучай*. *К/лючися* = *с/лучилось*.
Таким образом, слово **приключение** ~ необычайный случай, интересное происшествие...